# Run useEffect hook before rendering jest snapshot in react-test-renderer test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-test-renderer

Let's say I have the following basic component called `Basic.js`:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([{ name: 'original' }]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setItems([{ name: 'new1' }, { name: 'new2' }]);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>{items && items.map((item, i) => <div key={i}>{item.name}</div>)}</div>
  );
};
```

Using [react-test-renderer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-test-renderer), I can write the following test:

```
import React from 'react';
import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import Basic from './Basic';

describe('Basic', () => {
  test('renders', async done => {
    let component = TestRenderer.create(<Basic />);
    setImmediate(() => {
      expect(component.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Which generates the following jest snapshot when I run `npm test`:

```
exports[`Basic renders 1`] = `
<div>
  <div>
    original
  </div>
</div>
`;
```

How can I write the test so the `useEffect` hook is run and reflected in the snapshot? So the generated snapshot looks like this:

```
exports[`BasicClass renders 1`] = `
<div>
  <div>
    new1
  </div>
  <div>
    new2
  </div>
</div>
`;
```

Is this isn't possible, is there a testing library I can use to run this hook?

Comment: try with [`act()`](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html#testrendereract)

Comment: Have you found any answer?

Answer (score 7):

Use act

```
import React from 'react';
import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import Basic from './Basic';

describe('Basic', () => {
  test('renders', async () => {
    let component;
    await act(async () => {
      component = TestRenderer.create(<Basic />);
    });
    expect(component.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried it, but keep getting `Cannot access .root on unmounted test component`

Comment: You are a saint!